# How to add a date header for my chat module in flutter with firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I want to add a sticky date header for my chat module just like how WhatsApp has. I tried sticky headers dependency, but it didn't work out.

Chat Page Code:

```
Column(
    crossAxisAlignment:
        snapshot['senderUid'] == _senderuid
            ? CrossAxisAlignment.end
            : CrossAxisAlignment.end,
    children: [
      new Text(
        snapshot['message'],
        style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white, fontSize: 15.0),
      ),
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
        child: new Text(
          snapshot['timestamp']
              .toDate()
              .toString()
              .substring(10, 16),
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5),
              fontSize: 9.0),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

Comment: *it didn't work out.* is pretty vague. What didn't work out? Is there a problem with your code? What is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this package

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sticky_header

Or with **Slivers** and **SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate**